# Post Curl issue

Tags: php, curl

```
<?php
$url = "http://website.com/folder/index.php";
$data = array('id' => 'R98s', 'name' => 'Bob', 'content' => 'Hello');

$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_exec($handle);
?>
```

This works great, only 1 problem though,
id like a way to get the content response from the posted data in a variable, and not show as if its the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE ); // return into a variable
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
        $result = curl_exec( $ch ); // run!
        curl_close($ch);
```

And never forget the `curl_close($handle);` at the end.

Comment: curl_close() probably happens by default when your script terminates, no?  And possibly when the variable goes out of scope?   Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: It has to do with on-time resource releasing and overall good programming: when you no longer need a file/handle/db connection - set it free.

Answer (score 0):

I always thought you needed this too

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($handle)
```